# How can I get the date format in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm in a server application comes date 12/07/2016 15:45:39

Now how do I get this format and template output 12.07.2016?

**Markup**

```
<div *ngFor="let data of item">
   <p>{{data.created_at}}</p>
</div>
```

showing format
2016-12-07 15:45:39

and how to filter to get 2016-12-07 in template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `DatePipe` with `y.M.d` format.

```
<div *ngFor="let data of item">
   <p>{{data.created_at | date: 'y.M.d'}}</p>
</div>
```

[**Demo Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/RpJx5jkWqjsEphF7Fa9R?p=preview)

Comment: Pankaj Parkar, Thank you very much, I did not know about this, new for me))))

Comment: @AccessDenied That happens, Glad to help you, Thanks & Cheers ;)